# History API and domain-level urls

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I have two pages on MyDomain.com. The index view which is visible from MyDomain.com/ and MyDomain.com/Foo/Bar. Each view has an ajax call to the other and each one pushes the state using the HTML5 History API.

There are the steps that create the problem:

- Start at MyDomain.com/ (Works as expected.)
- Click the ajax link to MyDomain.com/Foo/Bar/ (Works as expected.)
- Click the ajax link to MyDomain.com/ (Works as expected.)
- Click the ajax link to MyDomain.com/Foo/Bar/

Now the URL appears as MyDomain.com/**Foo/Foo**/Bar/

*I don't want a Foo Foo Bar.*

My current workaround is to add "../../../" to the front of the URL, but this is inelegant and not foolproof. Another option is a regex expression to count the directory levels.

Is there a better way to get absolute URLs with the History API?

```
function push(updateElementID, controller, action, url)
{
    if (typeof url == "undefined")
    {
        url = "/" + controller + "/" + action;
    }
    var state = {
        id: updateElementID,
        controller: controller,
        action: action
    }

    history.pushState(state, null, url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to ensure that the base element of the href element in the DOM is cleared...at least in the following case, it works for me:  On your shared layout page (_layout.cshtml), reset the absolute URL within the DOM by placing the following within the head tags:

```
<base id="htmldom" href="http://localhost:59805/"/>
```

of course replacing your port # and on launch, replacing the root URL to the actual domain name.

By doing this, you are setting, or resetting the href property and specifying a base URL for all other relative URLs.

Now would doing it this way would affect any user-input data preserved in the page between back and forward buttons?  I'm guessing it would be fine, as the above only resets the href property, and any other info in the DOM should be there.